# Populate the ListView of a CursorAdapter with running totals

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListView that shows a list of Transactions for a bank account, the most recent at the top down to the oldest at the bottom. I would like to have each Listview item display a snapshot of the account balance after that specific transaction, all the way down to a footerview that would show the starting balance for the account. For example, suppose I open an account with $300, and I make two $50 withdrawals and a $10 deposit. I would like to see something like this:

```
| transDate | transAmount | accountBalance |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| 04/09/15  |    +$10     |     $210       |
| 04/05/15  |    -$50     |     $200       |
| 04/03/15  |    -$50     |     $250       |
| 04/01/15  |    start    |     $300       |
```

Currently, my transactions table only holds the transaction date, the amount, and whether it was a withdrawal or deposit, so I am able to display the first two columns above.

I could be wrong, but I don't think it's safe to hold the account balance snapshot in the database, as that field could be manipulated, and I want to do my best to ensure that all counts are reflective of the current balance.

For that same reason, I'd like the third column to be a calculated value when the listview populates, but I don't know how to adjust the CursorAdapter or the listview to do so. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I don't think it's a bad idea to keep the balances in the database.  However, if you gave this task to me, this is what I would do:

- Create a subclass of `ResourceCursorAdapter`.  This will handle creating the view for your list item.
- Give it a private `SparseArray` to hold balances.
- Override `swapCursor()` to iterate through the cursor and generate balances for each record.  Since each record has an ID, put the balance in the `SparseArray` with the ID as the key.  Then call `super.swapCursor()`
- Override `bindView()` to get the date and the amount from the cursor at its current position and put them in the view. Then, using the record ID from the cursor, get the balance from the `SparseArray` and put it in the view.

It's kind of a brute force approach, not very elegant.  And the performance will definitely degrade the more transactions there are.

I think that to really make this work you would need some reconciliation checkpoints so that you don't start with the zero balance at the beginning, rather you start with the last reconciled balance.  Otherwise, when you set the cursor on the adapter which in turn calls your `swapCursor()` method, it'll take forever to generate all the balances before the `ListView` displays.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I will let you know how it works once I get a chance to implement everything. If I kept the balance in the transaction table of the database, what do you think is the best way to do so? Should I insert it with the `ContentValues` or should I create a trigger that sets that field automatically? If I do store it in the database, I'm concerned as well about the inconsistencies if a user deletes a transaction.